# How to convert any Audio file to np.ndarray for OpenAI Whisper

Tags: python, fastapi, numpy-ndarray, openai-whisper

I'm trying to make a backend where I can upload an audio file and use the whisper ai to transcribe it but `transcribe` accepts type np.ndarray and the audio files are in bytes I'm not sure how can I convert bytes -> ndarray.

I'm using postman to send an audio file to this backend, but I will need to convert bytes to ndarray to use the `transcribe` method of whisper ai but I'm not sure how I can do it.

```
import numpy as np
import whisper
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import FastAPI, File

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/abcd")
async def transcribe_audio(audio_file_upload: Annotated[bytes, File()]):
    model = whisper.load_model("base")
    result = model.transcribe(audio_file_upload, word_timestamps=True, fp16=True)
    return {"transcription": result}
```

Error

```
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got bytes)
```

I tried using

```
audio_data = np.frombuffer(audio_file_upload, dtype=np.float32)
```

but got

```
ValueError: Expected parameter logits (Tensor of shape (1, 51865)) of distribution Categorical(logits: torch.Size([1, 51865])) to satisfy the constraint IndependentConstraint(Real(), 1), but found invalid values:
tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]])
```

but I'm begginer using numpy etc and so I'm not sure how I can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the below line we can convert the audio bytes to ndarray.

```
aud_array = np.frombuffer(audio_file_upload, np.int8).flatten().astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
```

```
async def transcribe_audio(audio_file_upload: Annotated[bytes, File()]):
    aud_array = np.frombuffer(audio_file_upload, np.int8).flatten().astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
    model = whisper.load_model("base")
    result = model.transcribe(aud_array, word_timestamps=True, fp16=True)
    return {"transcription": result}
```

Credit: https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/216#discussioncomment-3779531